# built computer left on copyright info

Tags: system-installation, helpfile

I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS iso file for Ubuntu desktop and put it on an USB drive after taking that USB drive and booting it leaves me at a screen looking at copyright info and a command prompt, Not sure what to do.The Photo of screen:

[image]

Comment: Could you update your question with the output you get ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please add some more details to clarify.

Comment: I changed the the question making it more clear

Comment: Can you please add an image showing where your are stuck?

Comment: Sounds like you're booting to a command prompt, rather than getting a GUI login -- is that right?

Comment: I added a photo, I never knew it would be this confusing .-.

Comment: You built the USB flash drive incorrectly, or used a bad .iso download. What tool did you use to build the flash drive? (I assumed that USB drive meant a flash drive... if you meant a USB hard drive... then please clarify) FYI: my experience indicates that if you can use it, a DVD Live build works more reliably.

Comment: should I just burn the .iso file to the disc? and if so which was I using the right version?

Comment: Burn the .iso file to a DVD and then boot from that DVD to install Ubuntu. Right-click on the .iso file and select "Write to disc" or "Burn to disc". DON'T just copy the .iso to a DVD and burn it. 17.04 is the latest version.

Comment: It may be that the boot order in the bios is set to only boot from harddisks, or try harddisks first - so take a look at the bios settings. Ubuntu did not boot at all - the computer did not find it. (On FreeDOS, see my comment below)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you've booted to FreeDOS -- this is a command line "clone" of MS-DOS.  There is no GUI for FreeDOS, and it won't run Linux software. It's not any kind of Linux, never mind Ubuntu

Better try again, and be sure it's the *Ubuntu* .iso file you're burning to the DVD or making into a bootable USB. I'd recommend using 16.04 LTS instead of 17.04; it's supported until 2021, rather than requiring you to upgrade every six months

Comment: FreeDOS often comes with a computer if you buy it "without operating system"; Nobody really uses it, but it's enough to test the computer in the shop.

Comment: FreeDOS is often enough to update a BIOS. At least for legacy BIOS, manufacturers often published DOS-compatible executables for that job.